# Import a file from Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I need to import a file selected by the user from Google Drive. I tried to use ACTION_GET_CONTENT but it seems it doesn't work with Google Drive, so I think I can use Google API to list the files with my own Activity, but I didn't find any easy example to do that. Is there an easy way to replace ACTION_GET_CONTENT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the NEW Google Drive Android API (GDAA), there is a method [newOpenFileActivityBuilder()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi.html), shown [in action here](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/PickFolderWithOpenerActivity.java). It may work for you. But implementation may not be quick, since some GDAA learning may be involved first.